# Bootstrap Tables - Multiple Sort broken for Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

The ["Multiple Sort"](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#extensions/multiple-sort.html) plugin (`showMultiSort`) for Bootstrap Tables is broken for Boostrap 4. The demo on the linked page is visibly broken.

The button is visible in the DOM, but it appears "hidden" to the user.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: getData(),
    search: true,
    showColumns: true,
    showMultiSort: true,
    sortPriority: getSortPriority()
  })
});

function getSortPriority() {
  return [{
    "sortName": "github.count.forks",
    "sortOrder": "desc"
  }, {
    "sortName": "github.count.stargazers",
    "sortOrder": "desc"
  }];
}

function getData() {
  return [{
    "github": {
      "name": "bootstrap-table",
      "count": {
        "stargazers": 768,
        "forks": 183
      },
      "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3)"
    }
  }, {
    "github": {
      "name": "multiple-select",
      "count": {
        "stargazers": 365,
        "forks": 166
      },
      "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)"
    }
  }, {
    "github": {
      "name": "bootstrap-show-password",
      "count": {
        "stargazers": 37,
        "forks": 13
      },
      "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap."
    }
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/multiple-sort/bootstrap-table-multiple-sort.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="github.name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-field="github.count.stargazers" data-sortable="true">Stargazers</th>
      <th data-field="github.count.forks" data-sortable="true">Forks</th>
      <th data-field="github.description" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I created this self-answered question to assist anyone else who has run into this issue. :)

Comment: You probably should add an issue on the plugin GitHub (which I suppose you probably know already)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by creating the following jQuery plugin.

```
(function($) {
  $.fixBootstrapMultisort = function() {
    let $button = $('.multi-sort'),
      $modal = $('div[id^="sortModal_"].modal'),
      $toolbar = $modal.find('.modal-dialog #toolbar');
    // Wrap the button in a button group element.
    $button.addClass('btn-secondary').wrap($('<div>').addClass('btn-group'));
    // Fix modal title alignment.
    $modal.find('.modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header .modal-title').css({ position: 'absolute', lineHeight: 1 });
    // Fix the icons.
    $button.find('.fa.glyphicon-sort').removeClass('glyphicon-sort').addClass('fa-sort').css('width', '1em');
    $toolbar.find('i.glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('fa-plus');
    $toolbar.find('i.glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('fa-minus');
  };
})(jQuery);
```

There were a few things I had to fix.

- The `.multi-sort` button was not wrapped in a `div.btn-group`
  element.
- The icon was a `.glyphicon-sort` rather than
  `.fa-sort`.
- I set the width of the button to `1em`, because it was defaulting to the width of the icon.
- The modal window title was not on the left.

---

### Working example

```js
(function($) {
  $.fixBootstrapMultisort = function() {
    let $button = $('.multi-sort'),
      $modal = $('div[id^="sortModal_"].modal'),
      $toolbar = $modal.find('.modal-dialog #toolbar');
    // Wrap the button in a button group element.
    $button.addClass('btn-secondary').wrap($('<div>').addClass('btn-group'));
    // Fix modal title alignment.
    $modal.find('.modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header .modal-title').css({ position: 'absolute', lineHeight: 1 });
    // Fix the icons.
    $button.find('.fa.glyphicon-sort').removeClass('glyphicon-sort').addClass('fa-sort').css('width', '1em');
    $toolbar.find('i.glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('fa-plus');
    $toolbar.find('i.glyphicon-minus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('fa-minus');
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: getData(),
    search: true,
    showColumns: true,
    showMultiSort: true,
    sortPriority: getSortPriority()
  });
  $.fixBootstrapMultisort();
});

function getSortPriority() {
  return [{
    "sortName": "github.count.forks",
    "sortOrder": "desc"
  }, {
    "sortName": "github.count.stargazers",
    "sortOrder": "desc"
  }];
}

function getData() {
  return [{
    "github": {
      "name": "bootstrap-table",
      "count": {
        "stargazers": 768,
        "forks": 183
      },
      "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3)"
    }
  }, {
    "github": {
      "name": "multiple-select",
      "count": {
        "stargazers": 365,
        "forks": 166
      },
      "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)"
    }
  }, {
    "github": {
      "name": "bootstrap-show-password",
      "count": {
        "stargazers": 37,
        "forks": 13
      },
      "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap."
    }
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/multiple-sort/bootstrap-table-multiple-sort.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="github.name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-field="github.count.stargazers" data-sortable="true">Stargazers</th>
      <th data-field="github.count.forks" data-sortable="true">Forks</th>
      <th data-field="github.description" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```